# Scala: Recursive search among elements of a list of elements

Tags: scala, search, recursion, constraints

If I have a class like this:

```
class Person (var name:String, var surname:String, var sons: Set[Person])
```

I want to have a control that a Person cannot contain herself between his sons and the sons of his sons.
How can I do this?

I had thought a recursive search. But I have to be careful not to create cycles.
I can use a Boolean as a guard and just you find an item that contains itself stops searching.

How can I implement this? Do you have ideas?
Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**
Thank you very much for your help. Good answers, but above all you had great ideas.
Now I just need a little last help to test this check on my small project.

My real situation is as follows:

```
trait ArchitecturalElement extends PropertyHolderElement with TypedElement{}

abstract class Component extends ConnectableElement with ArchitecturalElement {
  var subElements : Set[ArchitecturalElement]
  var interactionPoints : Set[InteractionPoint]
  //Here I put the control
  //A component cannot contain himself in his subElements and in subElements of it subelement
  def notHerOwnDescendant = {
  def notDescendant(ancestor: Component, current: Component, checked: Set[ArchitecturalElement]): Boolean =
  !current.subElements.contains(ancestor) && current.subElements.forall(
        p => checked.contains(p) || notDescendant(ancestor, p, checked + p))

  notDescendant(this, this, Set())
  }

 }//Component

abstract class InteractionPoint extends ConnectableElement{}

class SAInterface(  var name : String,
        var description : String = "empty",
        var direction : SAInterfaceDirection = null
        )extends InteractionPoint with ArchitecturalElement

class SAComponent ( var name :String,
        var description : String = "empty",
        var subElements : Set[ArchitecturalElement] = Set(),
        var interactionPoints : Set[InteractionPoint] = Set()
        ) extends Component
```

But I have an incompatible types:

type mismatch; found : a0Dominio.ArchitecturalElement required: a0Dominio.SAComponent

```
p => checked.contains(p) || notDescendant(ancestor, p, checked + p)
                                                //  ^  here
```

From a Set [ArchitecturalElement], I derive a Set [Component]?
Whereas Component inherits from ArchitecturalElement.

Comment: Just a little note: you have field `son` and it's a little confusing that son is Set of Persons. Maybe `sons` or `childrens`?

Comment: basically, you defined a directed graph, which you want to make sure does not contain cycles? it's an algorithmic problem, which can be solved rather easily. just do a BFS search, and "color" the nodes (persons) you allready visited. if you reach a "colored" node (person), you got yourself a cycle... meaning that person's is descendant from him/her self...

Comment: @om-nom-nom, note that *children* is already plural :-)

Comment: @om-nom-nom +1, but `children` is plural enough without the s.

Comment: Less `var`s, more `val`s, please!

Comment: Do you want a way (method) to find out whether a person is his own son (or grandson, so on)? Or do you need to prevent this happening in the first place?

Comment: Hi,
I need to prevent this happening.
I also just a warning (a println) if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method produces all descendants of the current person, while it doesn't get lost in cycles:

```
def descendants(stop: Set[Person] = Set()): Set[Person] = 
  if(stop contains this) Set() 
  else                   this.sons.flatMap(descendants(_,stop + this)) + this
```

You can use it to check for your condition. In order to detect arbitrary cycles, you have a positive result once you end up in the first branch of the `if`.

An alternative is to enforce the graph to be acyclic in the constructor/setters. This allows you to use a search without the stop set, since all existing instances are guaranteed to be cycle free and the condition can be tested with a slightly more simpler and faster approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
class Person(...) {
  ...

  def notHerOwnDescendant = 
    !sons.contains(this) && sons.forall(!_.sons.contains(this))

  ...
}
```

Or else, if you want to go all the way down:

```
class Person(...) {
  ...

  def notDescendant(person: Person) = 
    !sons.contains(person) && sons.forall(_.notDescendant(person))

  def notHerOwnDescendant = 
    notDescendant(this)

  ...
}
```

Disclaimer: I couldn't test this code in an IDE so no guarantee that it compiles and is correct. Nevertheless I hope it helps as food for thoughts at least :-)

#### Update

Here is an updated and tested version which handles cycles using the "graph coloring" solution mentioned by @gilad:

```
class Person (val name:String, val surname:String, var sons: Set[Person]) {
  def notHerOwnDescendant = {
    def notDescendant(ancestor: Person, current: Person, checked: Set[Person]): Boolean =
      !current.sons.contains(ancestor)
          && current.sons.forall(
            p => checked.contains(p) || notDescendant(ancestor, p, checked + p))

    notDescendant(this, this, Set())
  }
}
```

Some test code:

```
val abel = new Person("", "Abel", Set())
val cain = new Person("", "Cain", Set())
val adam = new Person("", "Adam", Set(abel, cain))

println("Adam is not his own descendant: " + adam.notHerOwnDescendant)
cain.sons += cain
println("Added Cain to his sons' set")
println("Adam is not his own descendant: " + adam.notHerOwnDescendant)
abel.sons += adam
println("Added Adam to his grandsons' set")
println("Adam is not his own descendant: " + adam.notHerOwnDescendant)
```

And the output:

```
Adam is not his own descendant: true
Added Cain to his sons' set
Adam is not his own descendant: true
Added Adam to his grandsons' set
Adam is not his own descendant: false
```

#### A simpler solution?

As a side note, I believe you could prevent a person from becoming his own descendant simply by sticking with `val` properties instead of `var`s. If the set of `sons` is immutable, you can't create a cycle in the graph since you need to have `sons` ready before creating the parent, and you can't add the parent to any existing descendant's sons' set. Note that I had to keep `sons` as a `var` to make the above testing code compile.

At least this is how I see it - however there may be some tricks to defeat this, using e.g. lazy evaluation which I am not very experienced with yet. So somebody please correct me if I am wrong.

#### Update 2

> type mismatch; found : `a0Dominio.ArchitecturalElement` required: `a0Dominio.SAComponent`

I think there may be a typo here: based on the declaration of your method, `SAComponent` should be `Component` shouldn't it?

At any rate, the problem is that you declare `subElements` as a `Set[ArchitecturalElement]`, so its elements are obviously of type `ArchitecturalElement`, which is not a `Component` (the inheritance relationship is the other way around). So either change `subElements` into a `Set[Component]`, or declare the function parameters `ancestor` and `current` as `ArchitecturalElement`.

#### Update 3

A new member method of `Person` to find all persons in the descendant graph which are part of cycles:

```
def descendantsWithCycle = {
  def findCycle(current: Person, checked: Set[Person]): Set[Person] =
    if (checked contains current) Set(current)
    else {
      val newChecked = checked + current
      current.sons.flatMap(p => findCycle(p, newChecked))
    }

  findCycle(this, Set())
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need time to study this solution. I will contact shortly

Comment: Stack overflow, if the graph contains cycles, which the OP wanted to test.

Comment: @ziggystar Have you suggestions on the solution?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help.
Now I wanted to try your solution on my real project, just that I have discovered a type mismatch.
I wrote the problem in question.

Comment: The domain is not wrong, I just checked. I'm working on a graphical UML. I cannot change the domain. I cannot even declare the function parameters ancestor and current as ArchitecturalElement,
because ArchitecturalElement has not subElements.
Now I see if I can find a solution. :-(

Comment: Hello, I am able to adapt your test to my domain.
But I discovered that I do not need to know if a Person is a descendant of itself.
I need a check on the presence of cycles, if a Person produces cycles and who produces them.
How I can adapt your text to my purpose? Also if I do not disturb. Thank you.